# Comparing year in a case statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to extract the year from a field and provide a filter on that, however, I have tried a few things to filter based on year and it doesn't work...it still displays the full date instead of the empty string.
here's my latest try:

```
,(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(SomeDateField) = 1900
        THEN ''
    ELSE
        SomeDateField
    END
)As 'Confirmed Date'
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  An error?  Bad results?

Comment: It still displays the full date instead of the empty string i want it to.

Comment: If it displays the full date, the year is just not 1900 in this case

Comment: when I do a year(somedatefield) it displays 1900

Comment: I don't really get what you want to achieve. Your statement will only show 1900 if the year part of SomeDateField equals 1900. In other cases it will return the original full date

Comment: @rigamonk That because you are using a Date value in your `ELSE` part, so SQL looks at the field on the whole and thinks its a Date columns and a `''` value in a date column defaults to 1900-01-01

Comment: @rigamonk Try the answer now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your case to

```
,(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(SomeDateField) = 1900
        THEN NULL
    ELSE
        SomeDateField
    END
)As 'Confirmed Date'
```

Since you are using a `Date` value in your ELSE part, so `SQL` looks at the field on the whole and thinks its a `Date` column and a `''` value in a `Date` column defaults to 1900-01-01 but it treats a **NULL** as a `NULL`

Comment: if it is a date column you cannot compare it without single qoutes as it is a string.

Comment: @developer You can coz `YEAR()` returns an INT

Comment: @SoulTrain you might explain _why_ NULL works and `''` doesn't

Comment: @DStanley Actually I wrote it as a comment to the OP but I will add it to the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the case statement something like this

```
    ,(CASE
        WHEN YEAR(SomeDateField) = 1900
            THEN NULL
        ELSE
            YEAR(SomeDateField)
        END
    )As ConfirmedDate
```

Comment: It's not comparing a date, it's comparing the year (which is an int).

Comment: and your `As Confirmed Date` is not going to fly